# Event Listener not registered or called on Doctrine Event

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have followed the instructions in the cookboock : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html
but unfortunately my EventListener does not get called.

service.yml

```
services:
      strego.acl.eventlistener:
        class: Strego\TippBundle\EventListener\AclUpdater
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist, connection: default }
```

And here is my Eventlistener to execute:

```
namespace Strego\TippBundle\EventListener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class AclUpdater implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

    protected $container;


    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $args->idonotexist(); // should crash if called
        }
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

and now my controller code, with which i want to test it:

```
public function testAction($id){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('StregoTippBundle:BetGroup')->find($id);
        $entity->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $entity->setTitle('update Name! #2');
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();         
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response("done");
    }
```

I have no Idae why my prePersist Action is not called. Does anyone see the issue with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`prePersist` is called when you save entity for the first time. In controller, you are updating existing one.

Put `preUpdate` and try that or in controller change from editing to creating new entity. You probably don't need connection:default in config.yml.

Comment: Thanks for the help, how is it possible that the event is also triggered during DoctrineFixture load? Even though the listener is registered, the listener is not triggered.

Comment: I am not sure I understand so just to clarify; you are telling that DoctrineFixtures does not trigger prePersist() listener? Honestly, I have no idea why that would happen but I am not using it for a long time. I forgot the reasons why but maybe this was one of them. Suggestion: if it doesn't work right, don't use it. All my test classes extend my own TestCase which then extends Phpunit. In that middle class, I put fixtures using regular $em->persist($entity) and all listeners are triggered.

Comment: Exactly, within Doctrinefixtures my listeners are not triggered. So you are using testclasses to load fixtures? I would prefer to still use Doctrinefixtures, because i currently have all my fixtures build like that with references.